# Tagmanager not pushing all tags when AjaxPushAllTags is set to true

Tags: javascript, jquery

Has anyone been able to get the Tagmanager plug in to successfully push all tags by setting AjaxPushAllTags to true?  The documentation indicates that Tagmanager can push all entered tags on every update to a hidden field in the DOM.  However, an inspection of the HTML shows that only the last tag entered is being pushed to the DOM.  I've set AjaxPushAllTags to true.  I've changed the default setting to true, but it pushes only the latest tag to the designated place in the DOM. Unfortunately, the documentation lacks depth on this particular issue.  If you’ve successfully implemented this, I’d appreciate your feedback.

Here's my code

```js
   jQuery(".tm-input").tagsManager({
        AjaxPush: '/ajax/countries/push',
        AjaxPushAllTags: true,
        AjaxPushParameters: { 'authToken': 'foobar' }
    });
```

Comment: What is the relationship between the hidden element and the AJAX-related options? (Why would there be one? They seem unrelated.)

Comment: From the docs.
Retrieving tags on <form> submit
By default, Tag Manager creates a hidden input field with a random generated name and stores its data in this hidden field as a comma separated list.

When processing the user input on form submit, simply parse the data of this hidden field.

Look for this hidden field in the examples above using a browser developer tool (such as Firefox Firebug). In the example you should see: <input type="hidden" value="Pisa,Rome" name="hidden-somerandomgeneratedcode">

Comment: The existing tags and the new tag exist in two different places in the DOM.  One workaround is to extract all tags from the various places, but this would defeat the purpose of the API.  I'd like to get it working as designed if feasible.